# How to change background color of form with a button

Tags: c#, winforms

So I am in VB and I'm trying to create some buttons so when you click them, it changes the background of my form. Instead of this happening, the background of the button changes. How do I fix this?

```
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.button1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.button2.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.button3.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.button4.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, you're not in VB - you're in C#.  Second, you can see that the code you're using is explicitly setting the backcolor of the buttons, not the form.  Try "this.BackColor" instead.

Comment: See how you're doing `this.buttonX.BackColor` to set the background color? Don't do that. That does exactly what it looks like it would do and sets the background color of the button. If you want to change the color of the form, you need to do that through an instance of the form class. Fortunately you're in an instance of the form class already, so it's as easy as `BackColor = <some color>;` It helps to [check the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form?view=netcore-3.1) which tells you about the properties for the form.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas Ah, thank you. I have noticed that it was because of the "this.button1.BackColor" but I tried removing that and tried other things and it didn't work. I didn't realize you just remove the entire "button1" statement to make it work.